# Serializing XML with data identified by attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an XML containing data within 'field' elements identified by id attributes:

```
<data>
  <row>
   <field id="firstName">Stef</field>
   <field id="lastName">Ben</field>
   <field id="city">LA</field>
   <field id="state">CA</field>
  </row>
  <row>
   <field id="firstName">Ann</field>
   <field id="lastName">Brown</field>
   <field id="city">NY</field>
   <field id="state">NY</field>
  </row>
</data>
```

My goal is to create a class looking like this:

```
class User
{
    private string firstName;
    [XmlElement("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }     
    [XmlElement("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to serialize and deserialize this XML to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put an xslt style sheet in between. Serialize and deserialize with attributes to "normal" XML and from there transform to the desired form.

Comment: Thanks flup. Some how I totally forgot about XSLT. Since I'm looking for a generic solution, this is the best option for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML to query your XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
var users = doc.Root.Elements("row")
                    .Select(r => new User
                    {
                        FirstName = (string)r.Elements("field")
                                             .Single(f => (string)f.Attribute("id") == "firstName"),
                        LastName = (string)r.Elements("field")
                                            .Single(f => (string)f.Attribute("id") == "lastName"),
                        City = (string)r.Elements("field")
                                        .Single(f => (string)f.Attribute("id") == "city"),
                        State = (string)r.Elements("field")
                                         .Single(f => (string)f.Attribute("id") == "state"),
                    }).ToList();
```

Getting XML from collection of `User`s:

```
var dox = new XDocument(new XElement("data",
                (from u in users
                select new XElement("row",
                    new XElement("field",
                        new XAttribute("id", "firstName"),
                        new XText(u.FirstName)),
                    new XElement("field",
                        new XAttribute("id", "lastName"),
                        new XText(u.LastName)),
                    new XElement("field",
                        new XAttribute("id", "city"),
                        new XText(u.City)),
                    new XElement("field",
                        new XAttribute("id", "state"),
                        new XText(u.State))))));
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin. This is actually the straight forward solution I was thinking about. The issue is that this XML's source is outside of my company and it's structure, fields names or number may change. So I was looking for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Linq and creating a list of dictionaries

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //XDocument.Load(filename);
var rows = xDoc.Descendants("row")
               .Select(r => r.Elements()
                             .ToDictionary(f=>f.Attribute("id").Value,f=>f.Value))
               .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(rows[0]["firstName"]);
```

Comment: Thanks I4V. This is a nice solution that employs .NET technologies, but in my case I prefer to use XSLT.